# SQL: how to join field records within one table to create a new table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am currently learning SQL queries and have a question as follows

There is a table Authored for this with three attributes,

**id author_id publication_id**

> Find the top 20 most collaborative authors. That is, for each author
>   determine its number of collaborators, and then find the top 20.

I am thinking of using this table to generate a temporary table of co-authors, i.e.

```
author_id coauthor_id
1 2
1 3
1 7
2 1
2 8
2 10
```

and then count the number of coauthors for each author and then find the max.

As there is only one table, operations like JOIN cannot be used. Anyone can help to give some suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: FYI: `SELF JOIN` still exists.

Comment: @PM77-1 thank you! I guess the answer I have accepted illustrated what you mean by 'SELF JOIN'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can absolutely use `JOIN` when there’s only one table. This is a very common way of getting data out of databases.

Example:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE Authored (id INT, author_id INT, publication_id INT);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO Authored
    -> SELECT 1, 1, 1
    -> UNION ALL
    -> SELECT 2, 2, 1
    -> UNION ALL
    -> SELECT 3, 1, 2;
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Now we have an authored table, and we want to join it to itself in order to see all the instances where multiple authors contributed to the same publication:

```
mysql> SELECT a1.publication_id, a1.author_id AS author1, a2.author_id AS author2
    -> FROM Authored AS a1, Authored AS a2
    -> WHERE a1.publication_id = a2.publication_id
    -> AND a1.author_id != a2.author_id;
+----------------+---------+---------+
| publication_id | author1 | author2 |
+----------------+---------+---------+
|              1 |       2 |       1 |
|              1 |       1 |       2 |
+----------------+---------+---------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

From here, you will be able to group by author, count the results, and sort them.

Comment: Thanks a lot! declare the same table as two table and then do JOIN works perfect. Just a bit of slow. Is there better way to do this or this is the practice for this kind of question?

Comment: Yup, this is standard practice. There are some tricks you can use in some cases to speed things like this up, but not in this particular case, and those tricks make it much harder to tell what’s going on. Example trick: if the conditions on one copy of the self-joined table are much more restrictive than the other, using a subquery or temporary table for the smaller part may be faster than the join. But that really depends on which version of what database you’re using, where this is the safe default.

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(coauthor_id) as nbr, author_id from co-authors
group by author_id 
order by nbr
limit 20;
```